# What is the easiest way to merge GIF and Audio files into one Video file using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have an audio file and GIF, I would like to merge both of them into one video file, I've done the following :

Converting GIF into Video

Looping the output video X time `X = (int) (audioDuration / 1000.0) / gifDuration;`

Merge the final video with the audio

**FFmpeg commands :**

Converting GIF into Video

```
-f gif -y -i input.gif -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -preset ultrafast -s 1080*1920 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0 gif2video.mp4
```

Looping the output video X time

```
-y -stream_loop " + X + " -i gif2video.mp4 -c copy looped_output.mp4
```

Merge the final video with the audio :

```
-y -i looped_output.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac final_output.mp4
```

The above command works, but sometimes the output video export with one GIF frame (no animation) and audio

Answer (score 3):

Use a single command:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.gif -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -preset ultrafast -s 1080x1920 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this command takes a long time to finish, for video with 3 min duration it's take me 5min to finish

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI libx265 is much slower than libx264 which is what you're probably more used to. But this is a completely different issue than the original question.